# Swashbuckle ISchemaFilter based on method

Tags: api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to set an ISchemaFilter for my API that will return a different model schema for different methods, depending on which properties of the model each method needs to process.  Say I have

```
public class Dog
{
  public int Legs;
  public double GoodBoiBarksThisLoud;
}
```

and then 2 POST methods

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowMeThoseLegs([FromBody]Dog sexyDog);
public async Task<IActionResult> Bark([FromBody]Dog loudDog);
```

There's no need for Swagger UI to show property info for Legs in the description of Bark, yet both target the same model object and it makes sense (imo) to pass the whole model object class as parameter, otherwise I'd have to split into subclasses which I find somehow not the best. (Think bigger here of course, my actual model has dozens of properties.)

What I would like to achieve is the following

```
...AddSwaggerGen(c => {
  ...
  c.SchemaFilter<DogSwaggerFilter>();
  ...
});

public class DogSwaggerFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
  public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
  {
    var method_name = getMethod("But how?");

    if (method_name == "Bark")
    {
      // return sub-schema of Dog with just property GoodBoiBarksThisLoud
    }
    else if (method_name == "ShowMeThoseLegs")
    {
      // return sub-schema of Dog with just property Legs
    }
  }
}
```

Which seems like it should be possible, the Filter.Apply seems to be getting called for each property of the model as many times as methods my API has implemented, so the reference to the method is in the background somewhere, just not publicly exposed.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use OperationFilter. you can use it like below.

```
    public class CustomOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (operation.OperationId == "Bark")
            {
                operation.RequestBody.Content["application/json"].Example =
                    OpenApiAnyFactory.CreateFromJson("{\"GoodBoiBarksThisLoud\":0}");
            }
            if (operation.OperationId == "ShowMeThoseLegs")
            {
                operation.RequestBody.Content["application/json"].Example =
                    OpenApiAnyFactory.CreateFromJson("{\"Legs\":0}");
            }
        }
    }
```

and in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(
    o => {
        o.CustomOperationIds(e => $"{e.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"]}");
        o.OperationFilter<CustomOperationFilter>();
    });
```

then you will see swagger ui something like this.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I had looked at that one but somehow missed it =)

A few comments to add, in order for the UI to reflect what I asked, it's operation.Parameters that has to be set (.Clear() first to remove the default list of parameters). After that any further custom properties can be added. RequestBody will or might be null, was for me at least.

o.CustomOperationIds(...) can be avoided if the methods were defined with "Name" ... as in HttpGet(Name="methodName") instead of just HttpGet("methodName").

Comment: You mention [FromBody] in your POST method, it means you are reading data from body then how come it will be null ?

Comment: My bad, I had a FromQuery, where it then makes sense to have the .Parameters list filled.